# Pandas, mean value of multiple columns after groupby on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Date    Station_nr  BD_val  TEMIS_val
0   2003-01-01  29  284.8   291.0
1   2003-01-02  29  302.5   291.0
2   2003-01-03  29  306.5   291.0
3   2003-01-04  29  306.8   291.0
4   2003-01-05  29  324.0   291.0
... ... ... ... ...
3539    2004-01-27  478 285.2   293.0
3540    2004-01-28  478 289.7   293.0
3541    2004-01-29  478 290.9   293.0
3542    2004-01-30  478 289.6   293.0
3543    2004-01-31  478 289.5   281.0
```

I want to get the monthly mean value of both Val1 and Val2 for every station there is.

So far I have used groupby on two of the columns, and then wanted to select both Val1/Val2 to take the mean from using the following method:

```
cols = ['BD_val', 'TEMIS_val']
comp_df.groupby([pd.PeriodIndex(comp_df['Date'], freq="M"), comp_df['Station_nr']])[cols].mean()
```

But this just returns the mean value of Val1, not both columns:

```
Date    Station_nr  BD_val
2003-01 29          295.448387
        57          282.258065
        101         310.516129
        111         268.071429
        232         289.806452
... ... ...
2003-12 400         294.733333
        454         298.176667
        473         308.433333
        478         309.306667
2004-01 478         291.330000
```

How do I get the mean values of both columns?

Note: Using a sample dataframe this method does work, so I'm not sure why it won't work on this particular one. Sample dataframe where it does work is shown below, for reference.

```
# Own made sample dataframe where this method does work.
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=100, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng,
                   'Station' : range(len(rng)),
                   'Val1' : np.random.randn(len(rng)), 
                   'Val2' : np.random.randn(len(rng))})
cols = ['Val1', 'Val2']
df.groupby([pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq="M"), df['Station']])[cols].mean()
```

Again to be sure, this code section above is how it should work, but it doesn't work in my case and I want to know what the reason could be.

Comment: It's working for me when I copy your data and run your code. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: What's the type of the column 'TEMIS_val'? I guess you would have this behaviour if you have a column of string for example

Comment: @BenoitFgt is probably right. I tryed your code as well and, as @enke stated before, it worked just fine, I just had to be sure to change `'Date'` column to `datetime`.

Comment: My date column is in datetime and both Val columns are float32. It works only with the last section, but did it also work with the data in the format above?

Comment: @B.Quaink what is `print(comp_df[cols].dtypes)` ?

Comment: Yeah I think that's it, it shows the Dtype of Date and TEMIS_Val being object, not the ones they are stored as (datetime/float). Think I need an extra conversion or .astype() to fix this. It's strange, as I make the dataframe from a list where the values are already float.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when creating the dataframe, the columns are stored as objects, not as the same datatype:

```
>>>comp_df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3544 entries, 0 to 3543
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----  
 0   Date        3544 non-null   object 
 1   Station_nr  3544 non-null   int64  
 2   BD_val      3544 non-null   float64
 3   TEMIS_val   3544 non-null   object
```

So prior I need to make sure that both are float, either by `to_numeric` or what I did `.astype`.